# How to disable all parent and childs if one parent is selected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

Here in first condition i was able to disbale all parents except current parent that is selected.

checkbox.js

```
     if (geoLocation.id === 5657){
                      var getParent = geoLocation.parent();
                      $.each(geoLocation.parent(),function(index,location) {
                        if (location.id !== geoLocation.id) {
                          var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
                          // Get **strong text**the model
                          var model = $parse(disableItemId);
                          // Assigns a value to it
                          model.assign($scope, true);
                        }
                      }

);
```

At this point i am trying to disbale all the child for the parents that are disabled in above condition. How to achieve that task with below code any help will be appreciated.

So far tried code...

```
                  $.each(geoLocation.parent().items,function(index,location) {
                    if(location.id !== geoLocation.id){
                    var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.children.data;
                    // Get the model
                    var model = $parse(disableItemId);
                    // Assigns a value to it
                    model.assign($scope, true);
                    }
                  });


console.log(getParent);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use angular, better express all of this in a model structure, and use ng-click and ng-disabled to achieve what you need.

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="item.disabled" ng-click="disableOthers(item)"> {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.disableOthers = function (item) {
  // iterate over parents and childs and mark disabled to true
};
```